# Catch adb messages in the device

Tags: android, logging, system, message, adb

Is there any way to catch all messages of the adb inside the android device - I'd like OS messages too, not in the log cat? If it possible I want to see the messages that are coming from the application while testing and sort them with algorithm to show in maketoast the message from the app?

Comment: What does the phrase "all messages of the adb inside the android device" mean? What does the phrase "OS messages" mean?

Comment: I ment logging some system/OS and app messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found what I was looking for

http://elinux.org/Android_Logging_System

Comment: OK then, but be noticed that from 4.1 Android only allow system app to read all the logs. Other app can only read the log that generated by the same shared user ID apps.

Comment: OK, if it is rooted you can do anything you want.